# Selenium webdriver click alert

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website http://bombayhighcourt.nic.in/party_query.php . Everything goes well until I scrape the results for the first time and go back to this page. Then the following alert shows up:[image]

I can see that the code responsible for the alert is this:

```
function validate()
{
  with(document.pqueryfrm)
  {
    if(trim(m_party.value)=="")
    {
      alert("Enter Party Name");
      m_party.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(m_party.value=="")
    {
      alert("Enter Party Name");
      m_party.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to click OK in this alert with this code but it doesn't do anything:

```
        try:
            WebDriverWait(s.mydriver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),"Enter Party Name" )
            alert = s.mydriver.switch_to.alert()
            alert.accept()
            print("alert accepted")
        except TimeoutException:
            print ("no alert")
```

And I am receiving the following error message:

```
UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Enter Party Name}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any error you're getting?

Comment: Can you show us the error text then please?

Comment: Apologies. The error message is related to the alert. I have edited my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an error in this line

```
alert = s.mydriver.switch_to.alert()
```

It should looks like

```
alert = s.mydriver.switch_to.alert
```

or

```
alert = s.mydriver.switch_to_alert()
```

Also you make same actions twice (`EC.alert_is_present()` allow to switch to alert as well as `driver.switch_to.alert`). You can simply use

```
alert = WebDriverWait(s.mydriver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),"Enter Party Name" )
alert.accept()
print("alert accepted")
```

Comment: In C# it is `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();`